# How to convert UTM Coordinate in C to Latitude/Longitude using WGS84 Datum?

Tags: c++, gps

Does anyone know where I can find open source code (in c++) that converts a UTM point to Geo (WGS 84)?

Thanks,
Liran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [GDAL](https://gdal.org/).

Specifically the code used [here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html).

There is also a Warp API tutorial [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180702062214/http://www.gdal.org:80/warptut.html) which outlines the basic use of the Warp API.

Alternatively, you can use the more lightweight [PROJ.4 library](https://web.archive.org/web/20161230000425/http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) (GDAL uses this internally).

Answer (score 3):

While not C++ per se, I have written it in Objective-C and could more or less be copied and pasted into C or C++ with a few minor alterations.

[UTMConverter example for iOS](https://github.com/palmerc/UTMConverter)

The part you want is a file called UTMConverter.m. It has methods for converting from lat/long to UTM and vice-versa.